# If 鳥肉 is chicken meat, what is duck meat?

Tags: meaning, kanji

鳥 means bird or poultry. It's understandable that 鳥肉 would be chicken meat since chicken is the most popular "bird meat".

But in this case where chicken has monopolized the meaning of bird, how would you express duck meat?

Comment: Related:  [What words are used for dolphin meat?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6625/78) and [Different conventions for animal meat](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6629/78)

Answer (score 4):

With the kanji for duck, of course!

> 鴨肉{かもにく}

Though 鴨 is more commonly written in kana as かも or カモ.

Comment: Note that 鴨 is for [wild ducks](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AC%E3%83%A2), and 「[アヒル](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%92%E3%83%AB)」 is for domestic ducks. (It seems we don't usually distinguish アヒル from 鴨 regarding meat, though.)

Comment: @Yosh, why would you want to eat your pet?

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Uh... I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly, but I might be confused about the usage of "duck" (and "mallard") in English. 鴨 seems to correspond to mallard, and アヒル is a word for domesticated 鴨. In Japanese those two are different words (unlike "duck" as in wild/domesticated duck), but for [meat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_%28food%29) it seems 鴨肉 can be used even if the meat comes from アヒル. Donald Duck is [アヒル](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%83%80%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF), by the way.

Comment: Domesticated doesn't mean they are a pet.  Dogs are domesticated, but so are chicken, goats, ducks, cows, sheep, etc.

Comment: @Yosh I just realised that there aren't really many pet ducks in Japan, so please ignore my comment. Your understanding of 鴨 and アヒル is largely my understanding as well. There just seems to be more of a personification of アヒル in Japan with characters like the AFLACダック hence it seemed somewhat less food like.

Comment: @lunkini Yes domesticated doesn't mean they are a pet. It is useful to note that not all dogs, chicken, goats, ducks, cows, sheep are domesticated however and some wild populations of each still exist. However as in my comment to Yosh, the ducks seen in the Japanese media (as company mascots like the Alfac Duck or Donald Duck) are written as either ダック (borrowing from the English word) or アヒル hence the comment about pets.

Answer (score 0):

Chicken meat is "tori niku" (鶏肉) and duck meat is "kamo niku" (鴨肉).